# Javascript in IE8 very slow, IE7 + others fast using jQuery, jQuery UI, nyroModal

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

The page is rendered within an nyroModal (loaded via ajax) and the DOM is manipulated quite a bit using several plugins before actually showing the page.

Everything is fine in non-IE-Browsers and IE7, but in IE8 the resizable and draggable of an div is very slow and crawles along.

I know [IE8 is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031615/loading-of-pages-in-ie-very-slow-compared-to-other-browsers). I know my DOM is big. I know i use a lot of plugins. My question is, what exactly slows it down, as other Browsers do it well?

I deactivated every plugin after each other to locate the culprit. Only having resizable activated it is still slow.

I used IE8 profiler and it says offset uses most of the time.

EDIT: I analyzed the page using dynaTrace AJAX Edition and it showes me that these 2 functions are responsible for the most exec time:

```
jQuery.fn.offset = function(options)
```

and

```
jQuery.expr.filters.hidden = function(elem)
```

both in jquery.js

i read somewhere that IE8 has problems with offset, but how can i circumvent this?

Edit2: I builded a test-page with just a link to open the page with all the resizing in a modal. works nice also in ie8 ! so i guess the big DOM of the modal-parent-page is the problem.

any advice appreciated!

Comment: I don't know your experience with jQuery, but you may want to look into some of the performance improvements given in this talk by Addy Osmani. http://vimeo.com/18846584

Comment: i allready implemented most of these speed improvements. very good talk though, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

[Dynatrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) has a **very good** javascript profiler. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your browser is not running in IE7 emulation mode.

Comment: i looked at developer tools and ie8 is selected

Comment: could you find selector, that runs slowly?

Comment: what do you mean by that? what runs slow is the resizing and dragging of divs

Comment: you have very strange result, because IE8 is **faster** than IE7. Could you share your page ?

Comment: not at this moment, as its for a customer and not considered to be online.